# LDAP Connection difference between Operating System

Tags: windows, vb6

i have the same method that performs an LDAP query on two different system. The method is very simple:

```
Public Function AutenticaDominio(ByVal user As String, ByVal ambiente As String) As String


    Dim Comm As New ADODB.Command
    Dim conn As New ADODB.connection

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim codiceBanca As String

    Dim currentAmbiente As String
    Dim currentName As String
    Dim trovato As Boolean
    Dim UserName As String

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    conn.Properties("User ID") = "XXX"
    conn.Properties("Password") = "XXX"
    conn.Open "DS Query", "XXX", "XXX"
    Set Comm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set Comm.ActiveConnection = conn
    Comm.CommandText = "SELECT SBAcodicebanca FROM 'LDAP://abc.cde.fgh.it/ou=bank,dc=cde,dc=it' WHERE uid = '" & user & "' and SBAelencoambienti = 'sbacodicesottoambiente=GEST,sbacodiceambiente=PROT,ou=applicazioni,dc=cde,dc=it'"
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Set rs = Comm.Execute

    If rs.EOF = False Then
       If rs.Fields.Item(0) = "099" Then
          Autentica = rs.Fields.Item(0)
          Exit Function
       Else
               Autentica = ""
       End If
    Else
        Autentica = ""
    End If

End Function
```

The rs.execute statement, return an "unspecified error" where i run the method on a windows XP. The method works well on Windows 7 instead.

The project is the same, with the same references and components.

Does anyone know where could be the error?

Comment: I finally end up with this solution: switch from standard SQL to LDAP query syntax. It Works!